# How to allow complex inputs, and complex weights to a Pytorch model?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, complex-numbers

Assume even the simplest model (taken from [here](https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/master/mnist/main.py))

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 32, 3, 1)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(32, 64, 3, 1)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(9216, 128)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(128, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = F.max_pool2d(x, 2)
        x = torch.flatten(x, 1)
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)

        output = F.log_softmax(x, dim=1)
        return output
```

When feeding complex data to the model,

```
output = model(data.complex())
```

it gives

> ```
> ret = torch.addmm(bias, input, weight.t())
>
> RuntimeError: expected scalar type Float but found ComplexDouble
> ```

(I didn't copy the entire stack trace, nor the entire training code, for question simplicity)

---

doing `self.complex()` after the model's `__init__`, as I normally would do `self.double()`, doesn't work, with

```
torch.nn.modules.module.ModuleAttributeError: 'Net' object has no attribute 'complex'
```

---

1. How to allow model's weights to be complex?
2. How to allow complex input to a model?
3. Which built-in activation functions support this?
4. Is anything also supported for 1d operations?

---

EDIT:

In the meantime, I found
[this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.09046.pdf). Still reading it.

Comment: Have you looked into [this repository](https://github.com/omrijsharon/torchlex)?

Comment: @Ivan thanks! looks like the github of the paper i found in the meanwhile. More than that, it looks like I am going to avoid complex NNs for dear life.

Answer (score 2):

As you normally did `self.double()`, I found `self.type(dst_type)` from https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html

In my case, `self.type(torch.complex64)` is working for me.